# Scientific notation above plot

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to know how I can prevent that the scientific notation (especially the fact that there is a sum of two numbers in scientific notation, which seemed weird to me) on the top of my plot appears.

I'd try to plot some data which has a finite real part and no imaginary part (all these values are zero). Therefore I expected the plot to do no weird things And so I can't figure out matplot.lib decides to plot this sum above my plot.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what are the actual numbers that are being plotted (it would be clearer if they would be included in the question), but if it is actually like 10**(-8) then you could plot normalized values (i.e., values * 10**8).

Comment: The values range from: 0.09768862  to 0.09768863

Comment: You can try setting the ticks manually if automatic fails for some reason. I think something like
plt.yticks([0.09768862,0.097688622,0.097688624,0.097688626,0.097688628,0.09768863]) might help.
However it is not very convenient as the y-number contains a lot of leading digits that are not changing in the plot.

I think it's better to consider plotting some other value (e.g. y = y0 + delta_y) depending on the context of your problem. In this case delta_y could start with 0.

Comment: `ax.ticklabel_format('y', useOffset=False)` see [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format)

Comment: btw, newer versions of matplotlib (~3.6.0 and above) should move the title up to prevent overlapping with the axis offset